# Problema al pasar variable con ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

estoy tratando de enviar una variable de javascript a php por ajax. Cuando lo realizo en la consola me aparece 'hecho', pero me pone que la variable IDbutton no tiene valor. Gracias de antemano.
Este es el código donde envío la variable con ajax:

```
<script>
$('body').on('click' , '.button_buscar_user' , function() {
 var IDbutton = $(this).attr('id');

 $.ajax({
  url:'Pagina.php',
  type:'post',
  data: { IDbutton: IDbutton } 
 })
 .done(function(respuesta){
  console.log('hecho');
 })
})
</script>
```

Y este es el código de php donde se recibe la variable:

```
<?php
 $IDbutton = $_POST['IDbutton'];
 echo $IDbutton;
?>
```

Cuando ejecuto el código me da el siguiente error: Warning: Undefined array key "IDbutton" in...
Este es el html del botón:

```
<td><button id=".$fila['numero']." class=button_buscar_user>".$fila['nombre']."</button></td>
```

Comment: La palabra reservada `this`, fuera de una función, hace referencia a la ventana; por favor edita la pregunta para agregar más código.

Comment: Independientemente que lo que sea `this`  en el contexto de JS, en el parámetro `data` **tienes que asociar cada valor a una clave**, por ejemplo: `data: { IDbutton: IDbutton }` ahí estás indicando que envías un valor bajo la clave `IDbutton` el cual podrás encontrar en la superglobal del método en PHP, en este caso: `$_POST['IDbutton'];` Considera también agregar a la pregunta los mensajes de error... *me pone que IDbutton no tiene valor* ¿? ¿Dónde pone eso?

Comment: @Triby Ya he añadido más código. This hace referencia al id del botón.

Comment: @A. Cedano También lo he asociado pero me da el mismo error. El error le he indicado al final.

Comment: @Mariguuan, agrega también el HTML del botón. Por cierto, en la petición AJAX no envías `idgrupo`, por eso obtienes el error.

Comment: @Triby Creo que ahora si lo envío, pero aún así me da el mismo error.

Comment: @Mariguuan, debes enviar un objeto con pares de `clave: valor`, en tu caso, sería: `data: { idgrupo: valorDelGrupo, IDbutton: IDbutton }` solo falta saber de dónde obtienes el valor del grupo.

Comment: @Triby, idgrupo se refería a IDbutton. Lo he editado para que quede más claro.

Comment: No veo en que parte del código intentas acceder a una llave `idgrupo` ¿ ?

Comment: @A. Cedano me equivoqué al copiar el error. Ahora ya está bien. Sin embargo sigue sin funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

Primero, algunas cosas básicas:

Los objetos en Javascript se pueden crear solo con valores (si se trata de variables u objetos), pero lo ideal es que lo hagas con pares de `clave: valor` para evitar cualquier posible inconveniente.

```js
let idgrupo = 5;
let IDbutton = 3;
let obj1 = { idgrupo, IDbutton };
let obj2 = { idgrupo: idgrupo, IDbutton: IDbutton };
console.log(obj1, obj2);
```

Tienes un HTML incorrecto, comenzando con los [ID, que no deben ser numéricos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) y, además, los atributos deben estar encerrados entre comillas, pueden ser simples.

Para solucionar el tema de ID numérico, aprovecha que a los botones se les puede asignar la propiedad `value`.

Y, para mejor legibilidad, usa notación de cadenas con [sintaxis compleja](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) en vez  de concatenar. Si se trata de una cadena muy larga, entonces de recomiendo la [sintaxis heredoc](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

```
<?php
echo "<td><button value='{$fila['numero']}' class='button_buscar_user>'{$fila['nombre']}</button></td>";
```

En Javascript solo tomas el valor del botón y, en la petición AJAX agrega `dataType` con el tipo de dato que esperas obtener del servidor, generalmente se usa `html` o `json`.

```
$('body').on('click', '.button_buscar_user', function() {
    // valor en vez de ID
    let IDbutton = $(this).val();
    // Ver que sea el valor y botón correctos
    console.log(IDbutton, $(this)[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'Pagina.php',
        // Especifica método y no tipo
        method: 'post',
        data: { IDbutton: IDbutton },
        // ¿Qué tipo de dato esperas obtener?
        dataType: 'html'
    }).done(function(respuesta) {
        console.log(respuesta);
    })
});
```

Con esto, ya no deberías tener problemas para recibir la variable, sin embargo, es recomendable que hagas alguna validación, en este ejemplo, con asignación ternaria, forzando a que sea un entero; si no está el dato en `$_POST`, se asigna un valor por defecto (cero):

```
<?php
$IDbutton = (isset($_POST['IDbutton'])) ? (int) $_POST['IDbutton'] : 0;
echo $IDbutton;
```

Comment: He hecho todo lo que has dicho y sigue igual, lo único que ahora pone 0 que es el valor por defecto si no existe $_POST['IDbutton']. He puesto el value, he utilizado sintaxis compleja, he puesto method en vez de type, he indicado el datatype y nada. Cuando pulso el botón, si que imprime la respuestas, lo que quiere decir que funciona, pero no lo envía. ¿Tienes alguna idea de lo que podría ser?

Comment: @Mariguuan, revisa el valor del botón inspeccionando en el navegador; actualicé la respuesta para mostrar el valor a enviar en consola, también revisa eso.

Comment: Si que me muestra el id en la consola (el vale del botón) por lo que eso no es.

Comment: No se, es muy raro.